# Java Android: result in the calculator displays integers(need float/double)

Tags: java, android, int, calculator

I wrote android calculator for learning java, and i have a error in app. If i input 5 / 3 - answer is 2, but i Need to float result (1,6). What i need to change?

```
    ArrayList<Float> result = new ArrayList<Float>();

    float number1;
    float number2;

    calcDialogDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResult);

    public void DIVISION(){
    number1 = result.get(0);
    number2 = result.get(1);

    result.removeAll(result);

    result.add(number1 / number2);

    calcDialogDisplay.setText(String.format("%.0f", result.get(0)));
}
```

Comment: Please read `String.format` documentation .... You just get what you asked for - 0 on decimal places

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
calcDialogDisplay.setText(String.format("%.1f", result.get(0)));  // should output 1.7
```

More info [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Formatter.html) (Section: Floating-point conversions).

Comment: *should output 1.6* not true ... 1.7